# Woocommerce: Creating variations - Manage stock checked by default

Tags: woocommerce

Is there a hook that allows setting the Manage Stock checkbox in woocommerce to be always checked when creating variations?

All our products are variable products (you can choose the products size), so it would be a global setting.

Thanks!

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

For anybody wishing the same option, I inserted this code into funtions.php of the child theme and it works.

```
if (is_admin()) 
{
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_manage_stock', '__return_true' );
}
```